# Бесконечная анимация CSS

Tags: css, анимация

Есть такой код

```css
div{transition: all 0.5s ease;transform:rotate(0deg)}
div:hover{transform: rotate(360deg)}
```

```html
<div>DIV</div>
```

Как сделать, чтобы бесконечно вертелся блок? Сейчас такое вращение только при наведении указателя мыши.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
div {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  animation: rotate 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotate {
  from {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Используйте [`@keyframes`](http://css.yoksel.ru/css-animation/) и `animation: ... infinite ...`.

```css
div {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transform: rotate(0deg)
}

div:hover {
  animation: move 0.5s infinite linear;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: green;
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
    border-radius: 50%;
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    background: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Infinite rotating</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    @keyframes infinite-auto-rotating {
      from {
        -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -ms-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -moz-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes infinite-auto-rotating
    /* Для Safari и Chrome */
    
    {
      from {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
        transform: rotate(0deg);
      }
      to {
        -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
        -o-transform: rotate(360deg);
        transform: rotate(360deg);
      }
    }
    
    div {
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      background-color: red;
      -webkit-animation: infinite-auto-rotating 5s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: infinite-auto-rotating 5s linear infinite;
      -ms-animation: infinite-auto-rotating 5s linear infinite;
      -o-animation: infinite-auto-rotating 5s linear infinite;
      animation: infinite-auto-rotating 5s linear infinite;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```